# colocar subtitle em chart.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chartjs, chart

Estou trabalhando em um gráfico, e estou tentando colocar um Subtitle que varia de acordo com o valor que o usuário escolhe. Não achei em nenhum doc como fazer isso, e tentei usar um Subtitle:{text:}, mas não funciona, e também não dá erro. Alguém sabe de alguma alternativa? Meu código abaixo:

```
function chart_graph(){

  var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-chart","line-chart");

  var chartGraph = new Chart(ctx, { 
                type: 'bar', 
                data: { 
                  labels: dataBar1 , 
                datasets: [{ type: 'line',
                label:"Dias de Estoque", 
                data: dataBar2,
                yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(250,250,250,0.0)",
                borderColor:     "rgba(255,99,132,0.9)",
                borderWidth:  4,
                },
                {
                label:"Valor de Estoque", 
                data: dataBar4,
                yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.9)",
                },
                ] },
                options: {
                  legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                  },
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'DIAS E VALOR(R$) EM ESTOQUE', 
                    subtitle: {
                    display: true,
                    text: subtitle_graph,  

                  },
                  },
                tooltips: {
                mode: 'label'
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    gridLines:{

                      lineWidth:4,
                      zeroLineWidth : 4,
                              },
                stacked: true,
                position: "right",
                yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
                ticks: { min: 0, beginAtZero: true, 
                       },
                scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'DIAS',
                               },
                },
                 {
                stacked: false,
                position: "left",
                yAxisID: "y-axis-1", 
                ticks: { min: 0, 
                         beginAtZero: true,
                         crosshair:{
                          enabled: true,
                          valueFormatString: "#,##0.##",

                      },
                 },
                scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'VALOR(R$)',

                               },          
                  }    ]
                        }
                          }   
                             });
                 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar um string array para a propriedade `title.text`, como notado na [documentação oficial](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html?h=title):

```js
var options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Opção 1", "Opção 2", "Opção 3"],
    datasets: [
        {
          data: [12, 19, 3]
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        text: ['Título','Subtítulo'],
        fontSize: 14
    },
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

[image: Renderização do código exemplo]

---

Outra opção é usar um plugin como o [Chart.js Subtitle Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-subtitle), que permite maior flexibilidade que a opção anterior.

Comment: Então, eu tentei fazer dessa maneira(array)(text: ['DIAS E VALOR EM ESTOQUE',subtitle_graph],), e ficou assim: 
DIAS E VALOR EM ESTOQUE, MP-NAC

Ele lê e printa exatamente o que tem dentro da array, inclusive a vírgula 
:(

Comment: @MarliBenicio aqui funcionou, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/qopkr0h2/. Confira se estamos usando a mesma versão e a passagem do array está correta (no seu comentário o `subtitle_graph` é mesmo uma string já definida?).

Comment: Estou com essa:
"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js" 

Então, sim. Essa variável(subtitle_graph), veio do controller(ruby on rails), trabalhei ela(ajax) e trouxe pra dentro do chart.js . 
COncordo que dessa maneira ['DIAS E VALOR EM ESTOQUE', subtitle_graph],  deveria funcionar, mas ele está entendendo a vírgula como uma string também e printando na tela, e tudo na mesma linha. 
Será que é por conta de versão?

Comment: É sim! Li o changelog da versão 2.7.0 (que meu exemplo usa) e nela foi implementado o suporte à títulos multi-linha.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigada!! É isso mesmo haha. Finalmente concluí a task aqui. Eu estava tentando versões  anteriores e não me toquei q poderia ser uma mais nova. :)

Comment: Eu sei que sai um pouco da linha da dúvida postada, mas estou tentando adicionar os valores de cada barra, fixos na parte superior de cada uma. Não estou encontrando nenhum Puglin específico pra essa função... Essa opção é possível no Chart.js?

Comment: Sim, existe um plugin oficial para isso. Veja essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31631354/3237900

Comment: Deu bem certo, obrigada novamente! :)